# How to request jsonp without 'callback' in the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xml, xslt

I am trying to retrieve information from an Icecast Radio station. The [API](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/server-stats.html) provides the `status-json.xsl` to get these data. Although the format is `xsl` but i believe it returns a JSON file.

However I noticed the server does not return the data if the url includes `status-json.xsl&callback=1`... So I am looking for an alternative way to get data without leading to cross domain error..

Here is my code:

```js
var dataURL = "http://relay-chi.gameowls.com:8000/status-json.xsl" + "&callback=?";
$.getJSON(dataURL, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The above code gives the error: `GET http://relay-chi.gameowls.com:8000/status-json.xsl&callback=jQuery2140976016339879229_1493590443216?_=1493590443217`

So with the fact that `http://relay-chi.gameowls.com:8000/status-json.xsl`, provides the correct data, how can I access it in jQuery?

Comment: Not all api's are ajax accessible. Use a proxy on your server or third party service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add `&` as query parameter initializer, instead you have to use `?`.

So the url will look like `http://relay-chi.gameowls.com:8000/status-json.xsl?callback=test&...`

However, I can see that the API does not accept callback.

Instead, using the below code you can get the data but the host `.gameowls.com` does not accept cross origin requests! (Open browser console for more info)

```js
var dataURL = "http://relay-chi.gameowls.com:8000/status-json.xsl";

$.ajax( dataURL )
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log('data =>', data );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```